# how to open the last opened files in ISE at the starting

Tags: powershell

i wanted to automatically open the last opend files in ISE with posh script, 
so i tryed to save filepaths of these files like the following.

`$action = {
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files | select -ExpandProperty FullPath | ? { Test-Path $_ } |

Set-Content -Encoding String -Path$PSHOME\psISElastOpenedFiles.txt

Set-Content -Encoding String -Value "Now exiting..." -Path c:\exitingtest.log

}

Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier Exit -SupportEvent -Action $action`

when i close ISE, exitingtest.log is created and has "Now exiting...",
 but psISElastOpenedFiles.txt isn't created.
it seems that ISE closes all opening files before the exiting event is executed.

should i use Timer event?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than saving on exit, save the MRU info when the CurrentTabs and Files objects raise the CollectionChanged event. This is the MRU ISE addon I'm using:

```
# Add to profile
if (test-path $env:TMP\ise_mru.txt)
{
    $global:recentFiles = gc $env:TMP\ise_mru.txt | ?{$_}
}

else
{
    $global:recentFiles = @()
}

function Update-MRU($newfile)
{
    $global:recentFiles = @($newfile) + ($global:recentFiles -ne $newfile) | Select-Object -First 10

    $psISE.PowerShellTabs | %{
        $pstab = $_
        @($pstab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus) | ?{$_.DisplayName -eq 'MRU'} | %{$pstab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Remove($_)}
        $menu = $pstab.AddOnsMenu.Submenus.Add("MRU", $null, $null)
        $global:recentFiles | ?{$_} | %{
            $null = $menu.Submenus.Add($_, [ScriptBlock]::Create("psEdit '$_'"), $null)
        }
    }
    $global:recentFiles | Out-File $env:TMP\ise_mru.txt
}

$null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $psISE.PowerShellTabs -EventName CollectionChanged -Action {
    if ($eventArgs.Action -ne 'Add')
    {
        return
    }

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $eventArgs.NewItems[0].Files -EventName CollectionChanged -Action {
        if ($eventArgs.Action -ne 'Add')
        {
            return
        }
        Update-MRU ($eventArgs.NewItems | ?{-not $_.IsUntitled}| %{$_.FullPath})
    }
}

$null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files -EventName CollectionChanged -Action {
    if ($eventArgs.Action -ne 'Add')
    {
        return
    }
    Update-MRU ($eventArgs.NewItems | ?{-not $_.IsUntitled}| %{$_.FullPath})

}

Update-MRU
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this a few months ago and discovered that a race-condition prevents this from working 95% of the time. The tab collection in ISE's object model is generally disposed of before the powershell.exiting event is handled. Dumb, yes. Fixable, no.

-Oisin